# validation_errors(), variable,

Tags: php, variables

I want to save errors from validation_errors() in variable, and dispay it in view.

I know how I can pass variable to view pass another view:

in controller:

```
$data['date'] = 'some_data';
$this->load->view('register/register_open',$data);
```

in view_open

```
<?php 
$this->load->view('mains/header');
$this->load->view('login/loggin');
$this->load->view('mains/menu');
$this->load->view('left_column/left_column_before');
$this->load->view('left_column/menu_left');
$this->load->view('left_column/left_column');
$this->load->view('center/center_column_before');
$this->load->view('register/register_view');
$this->load->view('center/center_column');
$this->load->view('right_column/right_column_before');
$this->load->view('right_column/right_column');
$this->load->view('mains/footer');
?>
```

in view:

```
 <?php echo $date; ?>
```

But I don`t know how can I save validation_errors() in array or variable, and pass then to view page. 
Could you help me?

Comment: Please tell us more about ` validation_errors()`

Comment: That was simply:                                             controller:                                           `$data['todo_list'] = array(validation_errors());
  $this->load->view('register/register_open',$data);`                                                                                     andview:                                                            `<?php foreach ($todo_list as $item):?>

   <li><?php echo $item;?></li>

  <?php endforeach;?> `

Comment: Are you using some framework / CMS ? Or own-written?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See this manual: http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user_guide/general/views.html

Assigning variable:

```
<?php
class Blog extends CI_Controller {

    function index()
    {
        $data['title'] = "My Real Title";
        $data['heading'] = "My Real Heading";

        $this->load->view('blogview', $data);
    }
}
?>
```

Now using it in view as:

```
<html>
<head>
<title><?php echo $title;?></title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1><?php echo $heading;?></h1>
</body>
</html>
```

In your case, try this in view:

```
var_dump($todo_list);
```

You will understand the data structure and how to process it.